# Convert SoftwareBitmap to WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Everytime when i want to convert my `SoftwareBitmap` to a `WriteableBitmap` I get the following Exception:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.

Here is my code snippet for that:

```
 private async void Start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            _MediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            await _MediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

            mediaElement.Source = _MediaCapture;
            await _MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
            timer.Tick += HandleTimerTick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private async void HandleTimerTick(object Sender, object E)
        {


            var frame = await _MediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync();
            SoftwareBitmap frameBitmap = frame.SoftwareBitmap;
            WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frameBitmap.PixelWidth, frameBitmap.PixelHeight);
            try
            {
                frameBitmap.CopyToBuffer(bitmap.PixelBuffer);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception ");
            }
        }
```

The line

```
frameBitmap.CopyToBuffer(bitmap.PixelBuffer);
```

is throwing the Exception.

I am debugging this on a x64 RemoteDevice.

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Look above: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Side note: *swallowing* exceptions like `catch (Exception) { Debug.WriteLine("Exception "); }` is a *very bad practice*.

Comment: I know that. It was just to clarify that there is the problem. But thx for the note

Comment: For future reference, the SDK sample is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue by using your code. It is caused by frame.SoftwareBitmap always returns null.

You can fix this issue by using the code as following:

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

        mediaElement.Source = _mediaCapture;

        await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private async void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;

        var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height);

        var frame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame);

        SoftwareBitmap frameBitmap = frame.SoftwareBitmap;

        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(frameBitmap.PixelWidth, frameBitmap.PixelHeight);

        frameBitmap.CopyToBuffer(bitmap.PixelBuffer);

        Debug.WriteLine("done");
    }
```

Comment: Works fine. Thank you

Comment: @Jeffrey I don't understand how this helps... It appears that the only real difference is using the return value of GetPreviewFrameAsync.  That doesn't make sense!  Doesn't that function use the passed VideoFrame to fill into?  It should be documented differently if so.  Can you also tell me if there is a perf hit if you specify a different bitmap pixel format in the InitializeAsync than in the VideoFrame?

Comment: @Jeffrey To be clear... it does work!  I'm just confused why.

Comment: Have a look at the "Important" section of the documentation, near the bottom of this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280228.aspx